# Adding data to DB fails without an error - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.3

I am having problems adding information to the database. I am not getting any errors, but every time I either try to validate or add information to the table Kids I get redirected to the main page "/" and nothing gets add. I really hope you can help me:

PagesController:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Kids;
use App\Guardians;
use App\Donations;
use App\Expenses;
use App\Food;
use App\Medicines;
use App\Inventory;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class PagesController extends Controller
{

     public function viewAddPage(){

        return view('add');
    }

    public function storeKids(Request $request)
    {
    $validation= array(
                      'KidID'=>'required',
                      'fname'=>'required',
                      'lName'=>'required',
                      'DateOfBirth'=>'required',
                      'Sex'=>'required',
                      'Age'=>'required',
                      'SchoolName'=>'required',
                      'SchoolGrade'=>'required',
                      'SchoolGroup'=>'required',
                      'BloodType'=>'required',
                      'Allergies'=>'required',
                      'enroll_date'=>'required',
                      'exit_date'=>'required',
                      'created_by'=>'required',
                      'updated_by'=>'required'

                          );
        $v1= Validator::make(Input::all(),$validation);

        if( $v1->fails())
        {
        return Redirect::to('add/list/')->withErrors($v1);
        }
        else
        { $poststudent=$request->all();
          $data = array('KidID'=>$poststudent['KidID'],
                         'fname'=>$poststudent['fname'],
                         'mName'=>    $poststudent['mName'],
                    'lName'=>    $poststudent['lName'], 
                         'DateOfBirth'=>   $poststudent['DateOfBirth'],
                         'Sex'=>   $poststudent['Sex'],
                         'Age'=>   $poststudent['Age'],
                         'SchoolName'=>   $poststudent['SchoolName'],
                         'SchoolGrade'=>   $poststudent['SchoolGrade'],
                         'SchoolGroup'=>   $poststudent['SchoolGroup'],
                         'BloodType'=>   $poststudent['BloodType'],
                         'Allergies'=>   $poststudent['Allergies'],
                         'enroll_date'=>   $poststudent['enroll_date'],
                         'exit_date'=>   $poststudent['exit_date'],
                         'created_by'=>   $poststudent['created_by'],
                         'updated_by'=>   $poststudent['updated_by']

                         );

        $check=0;
        $check=DB::table('kids')->insert($data);

        if($check > 0)
        {
        return Redirect::to('kids/list/');
        }
        else
        {
        return Redirect::to('add/list/');
        }

        }
    }
}
```

web.php (Routes):

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function(){
return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/signin',[
'uses'=>'UserController@postSignIn',
'as'=>'signin'
]);

Route::get('user/logout',function(){
Auth::logout();
return redirect('/');
});

Route::get('/home', [
'uses'=> 'UserController@getDashboard',
'as'=> 'home'
]);

Route::get('kids/list', 'PagesController@viewKidsList');
Route::get('guardians/list', 'PagesController@viewGuardiansList');
Route::get('donations/list', 'PagesController@viewDonationsList');
Route::get('expenses/list', 'PagesController@viewExpensesList');
Route::get('food/list', 'PagesController@viewFoodList');
Route::get('medicines/list', 'PagesController@viewMedicinesList');
Route::get('inventory/list', 'PagesController@viewInventoryList');
Route::get('users/list', 'PagesController@viewUsersList');
Route::get('add/list','PagesController@viewAddPage');
Route::post('/save', array('uses'=>'PagesController@storeKids'));
```

View (add.blade.php):

```
@extends('menu')

@section ('add')

<style>

.imagen{
width:400px;
height:auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.user{
position:absolute;
margin-top: -70px;
right:20px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:"courier";
}

</style>

        <form class ="form" action="<?=URL::to('/save')?>" method="POST">
        <h3><center>New kid Information</center></h3>

             <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="KidID" id="KidID" placeholder="Kid ID" class = "form-control">

                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mName" id="mName" placeholder="Middle Name">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date Of Birth">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Sex" id="Sex" placeholder="Sex">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Age" id="Age" placeholder="Age">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SchoolName" id="SchoolName" placeholder="School Name">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SchoolGrade" id="SchoolGrade" placeholder="School Grade">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="SchoolGroup" id="SchoolGroup" placeholder="School Group">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="BloodType" id="BloodType" placeholder="Blood Type">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Allergies" id="Allergies" placeholder="Allergies">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="enroll_date" id="enroll_date" placeholder="Enroll Date">
                <br>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="exit_date" id="exit_date" placeholder="Enroll Date">
                <br>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="created_by" id="created_by" placeholder="Created By">
                <br>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="updated_at" id="updated_at" placeholder="Enroll Date">
                <br>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="save" class="text" />

        </form>
@endsection
```

Kids Table:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateKidsTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('kids', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('KidID')->unique();
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('mName');
        $table->string('lName');
        $table->date('DateOfBirth');
        $table->string('Sex');
        $table->tinyInteger('Age');
        $table->string('SchoolName');
        $table->tinyInteger('SchoolGrade');
        $table->char('SchoolGroup');
        $table->string('BloodType');
        $table->longText('Allergies');
        $table->date('enroll_date');
        $table->date('exit_date');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

 public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('kids');
}
```

}

Kids

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kids extends Model
{

protected $table = 'kids';

}
```

I have been looking to this problem for days, and I really don't know why it isn't storing nothing, and it keeps sending me to the "/" webpage.

Comment: use DB in pagesController which is currently not available in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the fillable array to you Kids model

```
protected $fillable = ['fName', 'mName','lName'...];
```

You can then insert the record with eloquent, which is much simpler than the query builder:

```
$kids = Kids::create($request->all());
```

Your validator is quite involved, so move that to a FormRequest:

`php artisan make:request KidsRequest`

The add your validation array to the `rules()` method in `Requests\KidsRequest` and make sure you set the `authorize()` method to return true.

You can now type hint that in your store method:

`public function storeKids(KidsRequest $request)`

You validation will then be automatically applied.

So now we have the following method:

```
public function storeKids(KidsRequest $request)
{
        $kids = Kids::create($request->all());

        return Redirect::to('add/list/');      
}
```

Which I think you'll agree is a lot neater!

Your code is a little unorthodox, if you stick to naming conventions: `index()`, `show()`, `store()`, `edit()` etc' you can use resource routes instead which prevents you having to list each route individually, and try to keep your field names on you db format consistent, snake case (e.g. last_name) is preferred in laravel for db fields.

If you are struggling to understand some of this then there are some excellent tutorials on [laracasts](https://laracasts.com)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I followed all the steps, but still I am getting the same error :( It keeps sending me to the "/" page which is the main one. And it doesn't validate neither add anything

Comment: Have you added any `middleware`? Also, try putting a dd(); inside the `rules()` method of your `KidsRequest` does it still redirect you?

Comment: I haven't add any middleware. and I added dd(); to rules() and still getting the same error.

Comment: at first I had a Route::get('/', function(){
return view('welcome');

Comment: at first I had a Route::get('/', function(){ return view('welcome');});

Comment: sorry for all the comments, but I had that at my Routes.. but I took it off and still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you cached your routes? try `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

for sure you need to follow @craig_h answer and take care you're requiring `updated_by` in the validation statement and it's not made in the migration
so you've to add it

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `dd()` at some places in your code to make sure you actually hit the good controller actions. I suspect there is something wrong with your routes, maybe some `auth` middleware or something.